# SQL Regular expression Function

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this regular expression function and it purpose in the select statement.

```
create or replace FUNCTION REPS_MTCH(string_orig IN VARCHAR2 , string_new IN VARCHAR2, score  IN NUMBER)
RETURN PLS_INTEGER AS 
BEGIN
  IF string_orig IS NULL AND string_new IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;

  ELSIF utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(string_orig), '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]+', ''),' ',''),replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(string_new), '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]+', ''),' ','')) >= score THEN
    RETURN 1;

  ELSE
      RETURN 0;
  END IF;
```

//the REPS_MTCH function is  being called in this select statement. the select statement is to match names in the the Temp table name as REPS_MTCH_D_STDNT_TMP against the master table named as REPS_MTCH_D_STDNT_MSTR. what is the purpose of the REPS_MTCH function in this select statement?

```
SELECT
  REPS_MTCH(REPS_MTCH_D_STDNT_TMP.FIRST_NAME,REPS_MTCH_D_STDNT_MSTR.FIRST_NAME,85) AS first_match_score,
```

what is the purpose of the REPS_MTCH function in this select statement?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle are different products, with somewhat different sql and functionality. Which one of them are you using?

Comment: @jarlh is an oracle database but we use toad as the editor

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly.  The `regexp_replace` call is simply eliminating anything that is not alphanumeric before doing the comparison.  So the string "F.o.o.B.a.r" would be a 100% match to the string "FooBar".  The `jaro_winkler_similarity` function uses the Jaro-Winkler similarity algorithm to come up with an estimate of how close a match two strings are.  "Justin" is very similar to "Justine" but very different than "Bright".

Comment: @JustinCave. thanks. it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above function the `REGEXP_REPLACE` is removing all occurrences any non alpha numeric or pipe (|) characters.  After that the `REGEXP_REPLACE` is also wrapped in a redundant call to the regular `REPLACE` function which simply removes the spaces which were already removed by the `REGEXP_REPLACE` calls.  The test could be rewritten as follows and still behave the identically since the inputs are first `UPPER`cased before the replace operations occur:

```
ELSIF utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(
          REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(string_orig), '[^A-Z|0-9]+', '')
         ,REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(string_new) , '[^A-Z|0-9]+', '')
      ) >= score
THEN RETURN 1;
```

I simply removed the extra replace operation, the unnecessary lower case a-z and the extra pipe (|) character from the regular expression's character classes.

The `JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY` function just computes a score from 0 not similar to 100 identical of the remaining alpha numeric and pipe characters.  You can check out the wikipedia entry on [Jaro Winkler distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) if you want to know more about them.

Comment: i appreciate your answer and it makes sense now. i will learn more about the jaro Wrinkler distances. thanks